# How to "cast" String directly to Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I made an Activity to choose an app from the installed apps and get the launcher intent of the selected app and pass that intent back to an the starting Activity:

```
Intent intent = packageManager
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

        if (null != intent) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toString()));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
```

onActivityResult from the starting Activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == request_Code){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){                   
            intent = data.getData().toString();     
            startActivity(new Intent(intent));
        }
```

I extracted `intent` String and the `Intent` inside startActivity from Logcat and I get this:
`intent`String:**Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.providers.downloads.ui cmp=com.android.providers.downloads.ui/.DownloadsListTab }**
`Intent` inside startActivity: **Intent { act=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.providers.downloads.ui cmp=com.android.providers.downloads.ui/.DownloadsListTab } }**
(My app crashed because of this wrong Intent)
As you can see, the String I passed back to the starting Activity is the Intent I need itself(in String)
So is there anyway I can make that String an Intent without Intent's Constructor? Or maybe a way to pass Intent directly to the starting Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're making it "too complicated"... You're trying to use a String to start an Activity, not an Intent. Instead, simply pass the Intent you want to use. For example, try this:

```
Intent intent = packageManager
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

    if (null != intent) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

And then do this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == request_Code){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){                   
            startActivity(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and get this Exception: E/AndroidRuntime(6483): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.sec.android.gallery3d cmp=com.sec.android.gallery3d/.app.GalleryActivity }} to activity {xxx}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message.(I choose Gallery this time so the Intent is different a little bit)

Comment: Why can't I directly pass that intent to the starting Activity?

Comment: Actually it worked. I delete a value assignment and I forgot to delete the Log which logs that value inside onActivityResult value so the app crashed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes - I was about to comment that the problem was `println` which looks like a log thing, not apparent in the code you posted. Glad you found it!

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry for omitting it, I thought it would make the code clearer. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to pass a string to other activity , You need to pass it in extras.

`String messageToPass= "Hello Word!";`

`Intent intent  = new Intent(this, toClassName.class);
intent.putExtra("message", messageToPass);
startActivity(intent);`

and then extract in other activity , like

`Intent intent = getIntent();
String messageReceived= intent.getExtras().getString("message");`

Comment: Sorry if I understand your idea wrong but I have no problem with passing a String to other activity. the "intent" String in the question is the String passed back.